# Microsoft Graph - Getting data from a SharePoint List

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I am trying out Microsoft Graph, I wanted to create a Daemon application that will get data from my List in SharePoint Online, but for now I am trying everything first in PostMan. I am already getting the Access Token using the following

[image: Here is a screenshot of my Postman]

And here is my configuration in my Azure AD Portal

[image: App Registration Screenshot]

I tried to inspect the Access Token I received in jwt.io and it seems that the roles it has only has the following roles

[image]

when I tried the same token in my Graph to get data from SP List, I am getting access Denied

[image]

Using the same Access Token I was able to access "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users" but when I tried to use it to get data from a SP List I am getting the error above

[image: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users]

Comment: Could you provide more context/information related to your application registration in microsoft entra identity platform?

Your registered application may be lacking of necessary permissions.

You could for example try to call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users with your token, which should work.

Comment: For sure, I added a screenshot of the result of querying the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: Do you already granted admin consent for the SharePoint permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a missconfiguration of your app registration. You have assigned SharePoint api specific permissions, based on your provided screenshoot from microsoft entra admin center:

[image]

What you actualy want are graph permissions.

Resolving steps:

1. Open Microsoft Entra admin center
2. Navigate to app registrations
3. Select your app
4. Select api permissions
5. Click add a permission
6. Select graph api (over here you previously selected sharepoint)
7. Select Site.ReadAll

It should look like this when you´r done:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for pointing this one out, this solves my issue